# troubleshooting object 'tibble_update_attrs' not found in R

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have been having troubles with R this morning, first reading in a .csv file, followed by trying to use GGPLOT2.  To make sure it wasn't my code, I went to http://www.sthda.com/english/wiki/ggplot2-barplots-quick-start-guide-r-software-and-data-visualization and grabbed the following code:

```
df <- data.frame(dose=c("D0.5", "D1", "D2"),
                 len=c(4.2, 10, 29.5))
head(df)


library(ggplot2)
# Basic barplot
p<-ggplot(data=df, aes(x=dose, y=len)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity")
p

# Horizontal bar plot
p + coord_flip()
```

I can create the dataframe, but then get this error upon running the Basic Barplot code:
Error in update_tibble_attrs(x, ...) : 
  object 'tibble_update_attrs' not found

I updated packages, reinstalled GGPLOT2, restarted R-Studio and computer to no avail.  Earlier today I was getting similar errors about tibbles when trying to build dataframes from scratch, and reading in .csv files.

I have Googled but have not found a relevant answer (or at least one that looks relevant).

How do I start troubleshooting this error?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I did the obvious and first used

```
traceback()
```

and learned that when using GGPLOT2 all this "tibble-stuff" goes on.  I then:

```
install.packages("tibble")
```

and watched a number of errors fly by in the console.  I then:

```
remove.packages("tibble")
install.packages("tibble")
```

and success!  I now can make graphs in GGPLOT2 again.